# Get value of element

Tags: javascript, html

So I have code like this:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<body>
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<code id="output"></code>
<script>
console.log(document.getElementById('output'));
</script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get value of `output`? Because now it prints me `<code id="output">` instead of value shown at my page.

Comment: There is nothing in output, while you can access it using `console.log(document.getElementById('output').innerHTML);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your `code` element will have an `innerHTML` as the value you are referring to then

```
console.log(document.getElementById('output').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

using `document.getElementById('divid').value` you can get the value of inputs.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('output').value);
```

Incase of any HTML you need use `innerHTML`

```
console.log(document.getElementById('output').innerHTML);
```

Complete Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just access value of this element, like this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('output').value)
```

Comment: There isn't any `value` attribute defined for `id="output"`. Therefore, you can't get its value using `.value`